# Why does PyUSB / libusb require root (sudo) permissions on Linux?

Tags: python, usb, libusb, pyusb

I have been toying around with [PyUSB](http://pyusb.berlios.de/) lately, and found that it works beautifully on Linux (Ubuntu has [libusb](http://www.libusb.org/) 0.1 and 1.0, as well as [OpenUSB](http://sourceforge.net/projects/openusb/develop))... but only if I run the program with root privileges (with `sudo`, of course).

Can anyone tell me why it requires elevated privileges and, more importantly, if I can change the permissions somehow to make it work for normal user accounts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`libusb` allows you to manipulate arbitrary USB devices in arbitrary ways. You could format an external USB harddisk, for example.

In general, all direct hardware access requires `root` privileges, although I guess that actually full `root` privileges are not required, you should be fine with just `CAP_SYS_RAWIO`.

Comment: How do I set CAP_SYS_RAWIO with PyUSB?

Comment: `CAP_SYS_RAWIO` can be trivially leveraged to gain full root, so you don't gain anything by using that capability instead.

Answer (score 14):

You can change the permissions of your usb device node by creating a udev rule. 
e.g. I added the following line to a file in `/etc/udev/rules.d/`

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device", MODE="0664", GROUP="usbusers"
```

This sets the owner of the device node to `root:usbusers` rather than `root:root`

After adding myself to the `usbusers` group, I can access the device.

Comment: Cool... will give it a try soon!

Answer (score 12):

See the answer that I gave here:
[How can I comunicate with this device using pyusb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31992058/how-can-i-comunicate-with-this-device-using-pyusb/31994168#31994168)

Namely:
Set up a udev rules file for the specific device that you want normal users to be able to access. This will define the vendor id, the product id and a group.
The vendor and product id's can be found using the `lsusb` command.

1.
Create a udev rules file

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="171b", ATTRS{idProduct}=="2001", MODE="660", GROUP="plugdev"
```

Put this in a file called (for example) /lib/udev/rules.d/50-YourSoftwareName.rules (dig around in man udev for file naming rules)
NOTE: The old naming convention used /etc/udev/rules.d/filename.rules, that has changed.

2.
add the user names to the plugdev group

`adduser username plugdev`

3.
 force the udev system to see your changes

`sudo udevadm control --reload`   (that is minus minus reload)
`sudo udevadm trigger`

4.
unplug and replug the device
or
reboot your machine

The end result should be that all members of the group plugdev will now be able to access the device.

EDIT:
Note that on some systems the group `plugdev` may not be the group that you need. It can also be the group `input` in my experience, depending on what you are plugging in.