# What does it mean to give a process CAP_SYS_RAWIO in linux?

Tags: linux, usb

What does it mean to give a process CAP_SYS_RAWIO in linux?  How do I do that? (Specifically to give pyUsb access to devices. This is related to [this pyusb question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3738173/why-does-pyusb-libusb-require-root-sudo-permissions-on-linux))

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the `capabilities(7)` man page:

> ```
>   CAP_SYS_RAWIO
>           Perform I/O port  operations  (iopl(2)  and  ioperm(2));  access
>           /proc/kcore.
> ```

Capabilities are set on an executable with `setcap(8)`.

Comment: Note that `CAP_SYS_RAWIO` can be trivially leveraged to give root anyway, so you might as well just keep using root.

Comment: so... for launching a python app trying to access usb... I would set these capabilities on the command line when launching?  (sorry, I am out of my element here)

Comment: `setcap cap_sys_rawio=ep foo` would work if `foo` were an executable, but not if it's a (Python or other) script.  You could make your own wrapper or use `capsh`, but as Ignacio says, that's pretty much the same as running as root anyway.

Comment: Does this also work for USB serial devices? (The ones in `/dev/serial/*`)?