# Accessing USB data

Tags: python, pyusb

I wanted to read the usb data. for that i am using the pyusb library. and i had written a script

```
import usb.core
import usb.util

device = usb.core.find(bDeviceClass=9) # 9 is for hub type usb device

if device is None:
    sys.exit("Could not find Id System Barcode Reader.")

if device.is_kernel_driver_active(0):
    print "Kernal Driver Active!"
```

while running this its giving me the error. like

```
usb.core.USBError: [Errno 13] Access denied (insufficient permissions)
```

Comment: You probably need to be _root_. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3738173/why-does-pyusb-libusb-require-root-sudo-permissions-on-linux

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try to run the file using root user
to change the user to root

```
sudo su root
```

it will ask the root password

after that you can run the file with the all the access rights.

or use `sudo`, it will give all the access right of root user.

Answer (score 1):

Every direct access to an hardware (in your case USB) device need `root` privileges.

So, try to start as root!

Comment: its working, but when i run the script my mouse and keybord and other usb devices stopped working!