# Giving permission for USB through python

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x

I want to automatically have my serial connection get permission through the code instead of having to use terminal to give permission every time.

I tried using import os to use os.system() to automatically give permission but permission is always denied.

```
def checkConnection(password):
    if os.path.exists('/dev/ttyUSB0'):
        usb = '/dev/ttyUSB0'
        os.system('echo password | sudo chmod 666 /dev/ttyUSB0')
        return usb
    elif os.path.exists('/dev/ttyUSB1'):
        usb = '/dev/ttyUSB0'
        os.system('echo password | sudo chmod 666 /dev/ttyUSB1')
        return usb
    else:
        print('Is there a console connected?')
```

The error that I keep getting is

```
 self.fd = os.open(self.portstr, os.O_RDWR | os.O_NOCTTY | os.O_NONBLOCK)
 PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/dev/ttyUSB0'
```

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53125118/why-is-python-pyusb-usb-core-access-denied-due-to-permissions-and-why-wont-the

Comment: I would try to execute the programm with the required rights. Usually with sudo.

Comment: The error you show is not related to your code. Do you get an error running the code shown?

Answer (score 0):

I see what you're trying to achieve, I hear what you're saying, but this is not the right way to go about it.  Neither the use of `echo password` is sound, nor is the idea of giving `666` to the device.  Just add your user to the group that owns the devices, and leave it at that.